# Error using catch() with a .on() in firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving data in firebase using the following code:

```
  this.managerList = this.afDB.database.ref('users').orderByChild('managedby').equalTo(uID);
      this.managerList.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        this.managerIdArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
        this.managerNameArray = snapshot.val();
       });
```

Whenever a null value is returned, I get an error :
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property............ of undefined.

When I try to add a catch() to the above, it says cannot use catch() or then(). How do I use a catch() to take error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase's `on()` method attaches a listener to the data, which then fires once with the current value **and** each time the value changes. This means your callback can get called multiple times. Since a promise can only resolve or fail once, `on` does not return a promise.

It looks like your query does not return any result right now, so `snapshot.val()` returns null. And then `Object.keys(null)` throws an error. 
So something like this is closer:

```
this.managerList = this.afDB.database.ref('users').orderByChild('managedby').equalTo(uID);
this.managerList.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    this.managerIdArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
    this.managerNameArray = snapshot.val();
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try catch shuld be implemented as following , 
can you paste your code with trycatch that cause the error:

```
try {
  this.databaseService.saveCodesToFirebase(jsonFromCsv)
    .then(result => {
      this.alertService.alertPopup('Success', 'Code Updated')
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.errorMessage = 'Error - ' + error.message
    })
} catch (error) {
  this.errorMessage = 'Error - ' + error.message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just check the documentation of try/catch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

```
try {
  this.managerList.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    this.managerIdArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
    this.managerNameArray = snapshot.val();
  });
} catch (someError) {
  console.log('got some error: ', someError);
}
```

it is very strange, that the snapshot is null, it should definitely be an object, but you can also check it inside your callback:

```
this.managerList.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot === null) {
    console.log('some error');
  } else {
    this.managerIdArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
    this.managerNameArray = snapshot.val();
  }
});
```

Also: can you provide the whole error " TypeError: Cannot read property............ of undefined." What property can not be accessed? It looks like your use of "this" is not right here